# Tags can't be linked in Tag Wiki exerpt

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

If I use `[tag:debian]` almost anywhere on the site I get something like this: [debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian)

This, however does not work in the excerpt text of a Tag Wiki. See an example here: [debian-squeeze](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/debian-squeeze).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is intentional. The Excerpt shows up as a hover-box and the tag-style would be out of place in that box. The body of the tag-wiki can certainly use it though.

After some research, this has been brought up on M.SO before. Specifically:

[Tag links in tag excerpts not shown properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138023/tag-links-in-tag-excerpts-not-shown-properly)

Comment: I don't think so, as in my editing preview, it is correctly evaluated.

Comment: Sorry, I confused something there, the preview doesn't evaluate the syntax. But I don't think that it would look bad inside the box, as you described.